# using past continuous tense with tomorrow

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, past-continuous

What does this mean?

> like I wasn't dreading tomorrow enough having to give it back to him

I saw this in friend's series and I don't understand it.

Comment: That is not a full sentence. Perhaps you can begin by looking up how "like" is used in every day speech.

Answer (score 1):

This is colloquial spoken English, and without the rest of the conversation it's a bit difficult to understand.

The speaker is already dreading tomorrow because they have to give something back to someone. It sounds like they have just been presented with some additional reason to dread tomorrow, leading them to exclaim:

"like I wasn't dreading tomorrow enough having to give it back to him"